# Swift 4 GLKViewController update method not being called

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es, swift4

I am a new swift developer. I am writing code using glkit. I have trouble in GLKViewController not calling update method. Please help me fix it. Thank You

```
import GLKit
```

class gameController: GLKViewController{

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let glkView: GLKView = view as! GLKView
    glkView.context = EAGLContext(api: .openGLES2)!
    EAGLContext.setCurrent(glkView.context)
}

func update(){

}

override func glkView(_ view: GLKView, drawIn rect: CGRect) {

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
    glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
}
```

}

Comment: I would love an answer to this. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/glkit/glkviewcontroller) says a `GLKViewController` can implement an `update` method that the iOS rendering loop will call once per frame, but it doesn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegates!

1. In your `ViewController`, inherit `GLKViewController` and `GLKViewControllerDelegate`.
2. in `viewDidLoad()` assign `self.delegate` with `self`
3. Write out your `glkViewControllerUpdate(_ controller: GLKViewController)`

```
class ViewController: GLKViewController, GLKViewControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        ....
    }

    func glkViewControllerUpdate(_ controller: GLKViewController) {
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```